# How to change the value of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I mean something like this:

```
    function Test(){
        this.isConstructor = true;
    }
    Test.prototype.value = "custom value";
    console.log(new Test()) //should return "custom value"
```

Comment: It's impossible for `new …` to return a string. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Oh ok, i want to use it for a simple database but ill stick to my old one in this case. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You might still have an object whose `toString()` or `valueOf()` methods return the value you want

Answer (score -1):

```
function Test(){
  this.isConstructor = true;
}

function Custom() {
  Test.call(this);

  this.custom = 'custom value';
}

console.log(new Custom())
```